# Validating that email isn't registered in JPA

Tags: jpa

So I'm creating a signup page for a website and want it to check if an email (or username) is already in the database. I get all of my other validations to work, but for some reason this dosen't ever return true.

Here is the query for emailExist() (using easyCriteria):

```
   public boolean emailExist(String emailString) {
        try {
            QAccount_ qaccount = new QAccount_();
            JPAQuery query = new JPAQuery(entityManager);
            Account account = query.select(qaccount)
                    .where(qaccount.email.eq(emailString))
                    .getSingleResult();

            return true;

        } catch (NoResultException e) {

            return false;

        }

    }
```

I believe that there is something wrong with how the query is handled.

Comment: Sorry! Updated the question:)

Comment: Hmm, okey. Thanks for the help! I'm doing this for a project in school and we were told to add a dependency called EasyCriteria to help with JPA Criteria API. At least I have finally figured out a way to add custom validators. Is this a good way to do it or would you recommend a better one?

Comment: Thanks for all the help! I have managed to solve  it now. You were right in that the error was in the ```emailExist()``` method. I changed it so instead or returning a single answer I had it return a list of all matching accounts, and then just check the size of that list. If the list is bigger than zero, then the email/username is already taken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the faul was in the `emailExist` method. I changed it to the following code and the everything worked just fine.

```
    public boolean emailExist(String emailString) {

        QAccount_ qaccount = new QAccount_();
        JPAQuery query = new JPAQuery(entityManager);
        List<Account> accounts = query.select(qaccount)
                .where(qaccount.email.eq(emailString))
                .getResultList();
        if (accounts.size() > 0) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I wish I could but I have no idea what the problem was with the other method.